# How can I animate sort array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation

I want to animate the movement of circles when I sort the array, how can I do this?
At the moment, when sorting the array, the circles change instantly, but I want to see them move in places

I am ready to consider any solutions.
If necessary, I can use libraries.
thank you very much!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [sumCircles, setSumCircles] = useState(0);
  const [circles, setCircles] = useState([]);
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const handlerSumCircles = (e) => {
    if (e.target.value >= 0 && e.target.value <= 100) {
      setSumCircles(e.target.value);
    } else alert("");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < sumCircles; i++) {
      let value1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let value2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      let value3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
      rows.push(
        <div
          key={value1 + value2 + value3 + Math.random()}
          className={`circle`}
          style={{
            width: `50px`,
            height: `50px`,
            backgroundColor: `rgb(${value1}, ${value2}, ${value3})`,
          }}
        />
      );
    }
    setCircles(rows);
  }, [sumCircles]);

  const sorting = () => {
    // const sorted = circles.sort((a, b) => a.key - b.key);

    setCircles(
      circles.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.key - b.key;
      })
    );
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };
  console.log(circles);
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={sumCircles}
        onChange={handlerSumCircles}
        type="number"
        placeholder=""
      />
      <button onClick={() => sorting()} className={"button"}>
        Sorting
      </button>

      <div className={"wrapper"}>{circles.map((item) => item)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: well, you won't be able to use native Array sort - you'll need to write your own sort algorithm that somehow allows each change to "render" before performing the next step of the sort - unless you just want animate the final change - then it's probably going to be easier since you won't need to write a sorting algorithm

Comment: @Bravo I thought about it, thanks for the answer, I'll try to make my own method